# Decoupling a non-homogeneous system of differential equations using diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra

How to decouple following system of differential equations using matrix diagonalization

$\begin{pmatrix}m_1 & 0\\ 0& m_2 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\ddot{x_1}\\ \ddot{x_2}
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}
k_{11} & k_{12} \\ 
  k_{21}& k_{22} 
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\ 
x_2
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
F_1(t)\\ 
F_2(t)
\end{pmatrix}$

where $x_1=x_1(t)$ and $x_2=x_2(t)$?

Comment: Is $M^{-1} K$ diagonalisable?

Comment: Yes copper.hat, it is.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see how that helps :(

Comment: Oops, I missed the double dot.

Comment: The question reduces to determining if $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & \Lambda \\ I & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ is diagonalisable, where $\Lambda$ is diagonal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for:

If we write the equations as $M \ddot{x} + K x = F$, and if $M$ is invertible, we have $\ddot{x} = - M^{-1} K x + M^{-1}F$. If we suppose
that $M^{-1} K$ is diagonalisable, then
$V^{-1} M^{-1} K V = \Lambda$ for some $V$ and some diagonal $\Lambda$.

Letting $y = V^{-1} x$ and multiplying the equation by $V^{-1}$ gives
$V^{-1} \ddot{x} = \ddot{y} = - V^{-1} M^{-1} K V V^{-1} x + V^{-1} M^{-1}F = -\Lambda y + V^{-1} M^{-1}F$.

Then we have
$\begin{bmatrix} \ddot{y} \\ \dot{y} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -\Lambda \\
I & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \dot{y} \\ y \end{bmatrix}+ \begin{bmatrix} V^{-1} M^{-1}F \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$.
Let $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -\Lambda \\
I & 0 \end{bmatrix} $, then it
is easy to check that $A A^* = A^* A$, hence $A$ is normal and
so is unitarily diagonalisable.

In fact, it is not hard to show that if $\Lambda= \operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1, \lambda_1)$, then the eigenvalues of $A$ are
$\pm \sqrt{-\lambda_1}, \pm \sqrt{-\lambda_2}$, and a set of eigenvectors is given by $e_1 \pm \sqrt{-\lambda_1} e_3$,
$e_2 \pm \sqrt{-\lambda_2} e_4$.